# Vue: Register part of package as component

Tags: vue.js

I have got a wrapper around a package called `vue-awesome-swiper`, as follows:

`Slider.vue`

```js
<template>
    <div class="media-slider">
        <slot :sliderSetting="sliderSettings" :name="name">
            <swiper :options="sliderSettings[name]"
                    class="swiper"
                    v-if="slides"
                    ref="default-slider">
                <slot name="slides" :slides="slides" :code="code">
                    <swiper-slide v-for="image in slides" :key="image" v-if="endpoint"
                                  :style="{'background-image': `url('${image}')`}">
                    </swiper-slide>
                </slot>
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white" slot="button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white" slot="button-prev"></div>

                <div class="swiper-pagination" slot="pagination"></div>
                <div class="swiper-scrollbar" slot="scrollbar"></div>
            </swiper>
        </slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper';
import 'swiper/css/swiper.css';
import Axios from '../../../../axiosConfig';

// https://github.surmon.me/vue-awesome-swiper/

export default {
    components: { Swiper, SwiperSlide },
    data: function() {
        return {
            code: null,
            images: [],
            defaults: {
                'default-slider': {
                    loop: true,
                    loopedSlides: 5,
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
                    },
                    scrollbar: {
                        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                        hide: true
                    }
                }
            },
            sliderSettings: {}
        }
    },
    props: {
        endpoint: {
            type: String,
            default: null
        },
        settings: {
            type: Object,
            default: {}
        },
        theme: {},
        name: {},
        hash: {},
        numberOfImages: {},
        imageFormat: {},
        vehicleId: {}
    },
    computed: {
        slides() {
            if (this.images.length) {
                return this.images;
            }
            return [...Array(parseInt(this.numberOfImages))].map(
                (_, i) => {
                    i++;
                    return this.imageFormat.replace('#', i);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I have got a slot within this component, however it must use an instance of `SwiperSlide` for it to work. I need to register this as a component to use it.

However this isn't working as expected:

```js
Vue.component('slider', () => import('./components/Media/Slider/Index'));
Vue.component('slide', () => import('vue-awesome-swiper'));
```

How can I do this?

**Edit**

```html
<slider class="app">
    <template v-slot:slides="props">
        <slide :style="{'background-image': `url('img-src/${props.code}/theme/slide-1.jpg')`}"></slide>
    </template>
</slider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An import like this `import()` is gonna import the `default export` of the package, what you have done here is that you have destructured the import with `import { .. } from ".."` that means it has an named export.

However try it like this

```
Vue.component('slider', () => import('./components/Media/Slider/Index'));
Vue.component('slide', async () => (await import('vue-awesome-swiper')).SwiperSlide);
```

Comment: I have done this, however the slide still isn't being added. Updated my code to show how i'm using it

Comment: @MartynBall hmm ok. why did you wrap it inside an `<template>`?

Comment: See my `Slider.vue` component in my post, i'm trying to over-ride the **slides** slot.

Comment: Appears to work fine when using it directly within a component.

Comment: Never mind, I believe I know the issue. It's my Vue setup, so what you have suggested will work fine under most circumstances